# Can't connect to ftp server - Connection refused by server

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I'm new to this forum and ftp.

When I try to connect to a ftp server using filezilla, It returns -

```
Connection attempt failed with "ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server".
```

I run the Network config wizard. It returns -

```
Connecting to probe.filezilla-project.org
Response: 220 FZ router and firewall tester ready
USER FileZilla
Response: 331 Give any password.
PASS 3.11.0.2
Response: 230 logged on.
Checking for correct external IP address
IP 10.0.2.15 ba-a-c-bf
Response: 510 Mismatch. Your IP is 112.134.32.168, bbc-bde-dc-bgi
Wrong external IP address
Connection closed
```

I read artical and It says NAT routers, Dynamic ip cause to this problem. Is it true ?
How to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

This may be worth a shot: According to the [FileZilla wiki](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Network_Configuration#Active_mode):

> By default, FileZilla Client asks the operating system for the
> machine's IP address and for the number of a free port. This
> configuration can only work if you are connected to the internet
> directly without any NAT router, and if you have set your firewall to
> allow incoming connections on all ports greater than 1024.
>
> If you have
> a NAT router, you need to tell FileZilla your external IP address in
> order for active mode connections to work with servers outside your
> local network:
>
> - If you have a fixed external IP address, you can enter
>   it in FileZilla's configuration dialog.
> - If you have a dynamic IP
>   address, you can authorize FileZilla to obtain your external IP
>   address from a special website. This will occur automatically each
>   time FileZilla is started. No information will be submitted to the
>   website (regardless of FileZilla version).

According to the wiki, you should be able to open up Setings, under Connection select the `Active Mode` tab, and for the `Get external IP address from the following URL...` field put `http://ip.filezilla-project.org/ip.php` (Can't vouch for that because it just said 127.0.0.1 when I tried it in the browser, but it may know the difference). I would just try entering in my external IP address manually first.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like this is set on the server. My guess is it limits access based on IP address. So if your address is not on the list the server has, then access is denied. You cannot change this on the client side, unless you can change to an address that is on the list.